# To Show: $4k+3$ can't be written as $a^2+b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I'm studying Introduction to Arithmetic Theory and I see this question:

Show that any number of the form $4k+3$ can't be written as $a^2+b^2$ where $a,b$ are natural numbers.

I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that the square of an integer is congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ cannot be both odd or both even because $a^2+b^2$ would be even and $4k+3$ is odd. So WLOG we can write $a=2m+1$ and $b=2n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$, from where we get $a^2+b^2=4(m^2+m+n^2)+1$ which cannot be of the form $4k+3$

Answer (score 1):

If $k\equiv 0\pmod 4$: $k^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$.
If $k\equiv 1\pmod 4$: $k^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$.
If $k\equiv 2\pmod 4$: $k^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$.
If $k\equiv 3\pmod 4$: $k^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

So no matter what $a, b$ is modulo $4$, the sum of their squares will be $0, 1$ or $2$ modulo 4, not $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply consider this question in cases:

Case 1: Suppose *a* is odd and *b* is odd, then  *a=2m+1* and *b=2n+1* for some whole numbers *m* and *n*.

$${a^2+b^2=(2m+1)^2 +(2n+1)^2=4(m^2+n^2+m+n)+2=4k+2}$$

Case 2:Suppose *a* is odd and *b* is even, then *a=2m+1* and *b=2n* for some whole numbers *m* and *n*.

$${a^2+b^2=(2m+1)^2+(2n)^2=4(m^2+n^2+m)+1=4k+1}$$

Case3: Suppose *a* is even and *b* is odd, then *a=2m* and *b=2n+1* for some whole numbers *m* and *n*.

$${a^2+b^2=(2m)^2+(2n+1)^2=4(m^2+n^2+n)+1=4k+1}$$

Case4: Suppose  *a* is even and *b* is even, then *a=2m* and *b=2n* for some whole numbers *m* and *n*.

$${a^2+b^2=(2m)^2+(2n)^2=4(m^2+n^2)=4k}$$

By analysing all the cases You will get that sum of squares of two natural numbers can be only of the form 4k, 4k+1 or 4k+2.

I know this proof is long and boring but it is easiest to understand.

Comment: Case 2 and 3 are essentially the same, since the problem is symmetric in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @BrazilianCérebro, yes they are. I just added as two different cases to give a complete proof to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the equation modulo 4 and then look at the different values $a^2$ and $b^2$ take on. Is it possible that $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 3 \mod 4$?